# takePicture() always freeze for seconds

Tags: android, android-camera

I experienced 2 strange thing when I pressed the shutter button on my `CameraActivity`

1. On device 2.3 and 4.0 (Galaxy Ace II, Nexus One and Galaxy Nexus),
   it will freeze for about 2 seconds then proceed to `nextActivity`.
2. Only Galaxy Ace 2.3.6, it will give me a garbled pixels like the pic
   below during the freezing period of time, but it can give me the correct image later in `nextActivity`.

[image: garbled pixels]

At first I thought something might be wrong or time consuming in my `PicutureCallback` method, but it seems ok? And I can't understand why this garbled pixels will show up only on Galaxy Ace.

So will there be a better way to handle the `PictureCallback` to make it quicker?

There's no error log, so I just put my related code:

```
// I call the takePicture in my button listener.
camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

// here's the picture callback
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


        new ShutterHandler(data).execute();
    }

    class ShutterHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        Bitmap bm;
        String timeStamp;
        String filename;
        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, nextActivity.class);

        // a tricky way to pass data into the AsyncTask
        public ShutterHandler(byte[] data) {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // simply generate a time stamp as filename
            timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            filename = timeStamp + ".jpg";
            Uri path;
            try {

                // save file to app's private folder
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);              
                // retrieve Uri from the file
                path = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath(filename));

                Log.d("CameraActivity", "file saved to: " + path);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

                // launch ShowMarkersActivity
                String pathString = path.getPath();
                nextIntent.putExtra("IMG", pathString);
                nextIntent.putExtra("FileName", filename);
                nextIntent.putExtra("FLAG", true);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("CameraActivity", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("CameraActivity", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;                        
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            CameraActivity.this.startActivity(nextIntent);
            finish();
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Regarding Ace, how do you get the garbled picture? From preview callback?

Comment: @AlexCohn right after I press the shutter button, it will show me a garbled pixels like the picture above

Comment: It's not a good idea to continue receiving preview after you start capture. If you want to "freeze" the preview on the screen, you should overlay the SurfaceView with an ImageView and put there the result of latest preview callback (this method is too slow to display continuous preview, but OK for frozen screen).

Comment: @AlexCohn thx, what I'm trying to do is: when user touch the shutter button, the picture will be taken and write to an internal cache/storage, then immediately switch to the next activity. So basically I am not intend to freeze the preview

Comment: Fair enough, but I refer to that unpleasant moment between the shutter button and the picture callback.

Comment: @AlexCohn So could u give me some suggestion upon this issue? I applied the code but can't test it on Galaxy Ace until Monday.

Comment: @AlexCohn I followed ur instruction and tried on Ace, still got the garbled pixel right after I press the shutter button, but it is more responsive. Any idea for the garbled pixels?

Comment: You should hide the preview surface as soon as the shutter is pressed. What you display instead may vary. One possibility is to save the last preview buffer, convert it into a bitmap and display the latter over the area where the preview used to be.

Comment: @AlexCohn thx mate, I'll try it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask the camera picture callback to return jpeg format, it will all be significantly faster. Still the picture callback is slow on most of the available devices.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I did call this method `public final void takePicture (Camera.ShutterCallback shutter, Camera.PictureCallback raw, Camera.PictureCallback jpeg)`, please refer to the 2nd line of my snippet: `camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);` Is that what you mean? thx :)

Comment: But why do you decode it into a bitmap and encode the bitmap back to jpg? Can't you write the jpeg byte array to the file without these time-consuming conversions?

Comment: Ah, I haven't think about that. did u mean: `onPictureTaken`'s byte data is already jpeg encoded?

Comment: I looked my code, I passed the byte and then use BitmapFactory to encode the byte array into JPEG. So should I write the byte array directly into a file?

Comment: I found it at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-picture  thx